# How to calculate height of a thought line over a known spot in 3rd person view?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, modding, linear-algebra, third-person-view

Assuming a player object with third-person-view is in a **3d room** and the center of the screen has a dot - let's call it "*cursorTarget*".

All I have is the position of the player, the position 5 meters in front of it - let's call it "*spot*" - and (if necessary) the position where the *cursorTarget* touches the ground if it's below the horizon.

With that given data, is it possible to calculate the **height** of the (thought) line between player and *cursorTarget* right **above the *spot***?

[image]

I firstly thought of the intercept theorem, but I lack of knowledge of the camera height in that third-person-view.

Kind regards,
Stacky

Comment: Are you using any game engine (Unity, for instance)? If so, you probably have the position and height of the camera. An idea would be to normalize the heights from the `cursorTarget` height (i.e. make it 0, and discount its height to the `camera` height) and then use the similarity of triangles to calculate the height of `spot` from the normalized height of the `camera` and the horizontal distances between the objects.

Comment: I'm not developing the game, I'm modding. So no, I don't use any game engine. As for the idea though, that's a good start but I still don't have the camera height. :(

Comment: I see. Well, what game are you modding? Perhaps you should add this information to the question, since it might help you get better answers from people experienced in that particular game (or in modding in general). Good luck mate. :)

Comment: Pretty sure you're going to need a bit more information than that. Do you know how far back the camera is behind the player? Do you know the angle between the camera and the floor? Do you know the distance between the camera and the point where it intersects with the floor? You're going to need some more data before you can calculate this value, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I just found out that there is a command I can get the camera position from. So now I know that and I've done some math, but the ratio of the distances (`cursorTarget-spot`, `cursorTarget-cameraPos`) is not the same as the ratio of the heights. I assume I'm doing something wrong, because according to the intercept theorem they should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, there is a command to get the height of the camera above ground. It's called "[positionCameraToWorld](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/positionCameraToWorld)" and with that it's possible to get the spot height by applying the intercept theoreme.
Pseudo code:

```
cameraPosition = positionCameraToWorld [0, 0, 0]; //result = [x, y, z]
cameraHeight   = cameraPosition[2];

distance_cursor_camera = cursorTarget distance2D cameraPosition;
distance_cursor_spot   = cursorTarget distance2D spot;

ratio_distances = distance_cursor_camera / distance_cursor_spot;
spotHeight = cameraHeight / ratio_distances; //height of the red line in the above image
```